# How to use first:child and last:child after v-for in Vue.js?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am having trouble manipulating the grid on `v-for` using `first-child and` last-child in `Vue.js.`

Code:

```
<div id="grid">
<NewsCard class="elements" v-for="perNews in news" :key="perNews.id" :news="perNews"></NewsCard>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap : 1rem;
}
#grid .elements > *:first-child,
#grid .elements > *:last-child {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 1rem;
        grid-column: 1 / span 2;
        align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your style with the following code

```
#grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap : 1rem;
}
#grid .elements:first-of-type,
#grid .elements:last-of-type{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Enjoy!